# How to exclude media files from Wordpress RSS feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have custom RSS template for news aggregator. Is it possible to exclude all media files like images/video from `the_content_feed();` ? 
I need to display a plain text.

Here is my template

```
header( 'Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type( 'rss-http' ) . '; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
$frequency  = 1;       
$duration   = 'hourly'; 
$postimages = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' );
if ( $postimages ) {
    $postimage = $postimages[0];
} else {
    $postimage = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg';
}


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ."\r\n"; ?>
<rss xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title><?php bloginfo_rss( 'name' ); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
        <link><?php bloginfo_rss( 'url' ) ?></link>
        <description><?php bloginfo_rss( 'description' ) ?></description>
        <yandex:logo></yandex:logo>
        <yandex:logo type="square"></yandex:logo>
        <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0200', get_lastpostmodified( 'GMT' ), false ); ?></lastBuildDate>
        <language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>


        <?php do_action( 'rss2_head' ); ?>
        <?php while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <item>
                <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
                <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
                <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
                <author><?php the_author(); ?></author>
                <enclosure url="<?php echo esc_url( $postimage ); ?>" type="image/jpeg" />
                <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0200', get_date_from_gmt(get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true)), false ); ?></pubDate>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]>
                </description>
                <yandex:full-text>
                    <![CDATA[<?php the_content_feed();  ?>]]>
                </yandex:full-text>
            </item>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I've tried to use this filter, but had no luck :(

```
add_filter( "the_content_feed", "excludeimg" ) ;
function excludeimg($content) {
     $content = preg_replace('#(<img.*?>).*?(/>)#', '$1$2', $content);
     return $content; 
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

To show plain text from the articles in your RSS feed just change `the_content_feed();` to  `echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );` in your feed template.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.